# How to scale images for a consistent image size

Tags: jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am putting together a slide presentation using a jquery plugin called 'slick' (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) using django and a bootstrap 3 template. I've got a basic carousel working  using a django template that looks like:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div><IMG src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSj2c33fdt1ugB8VBuE5V37wnmPoxWMknX9JnGycNiH2yr3BpDKVA"></div>

    <div><IMG src="{% static 'img/slides/slide1.jpg' %}"></div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>
```

After adding the last slide I notice that the forward backward buttons were pushed way down (please see screenshot). I'm guessing this is related to the size of the slide. I just added.

I'm not a front end person so this is probably a basic question, but what is the best way to have a consistent size of slides. Can they be autoscaled to fit a predetermined size if they are different in original size. I'm making some of these by hand as well so I could in theory I could set them to a specific size if that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the property `width` in the `img` selector:

```
<div><img width="100%" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSj2c33fdt1ugB8VBuE5V37wnmPoxWMknX9JnGycNiH2yr3BpDKVA"></div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ws4ty6wo/

Answer (score 1):

- The best way to do that would be to resize the images dynamically on
  the server, python and django I'm sure have a million ways to do that.
- The easiest way to do this in the browser, if you're
  going to require users to use modern (IE 9+) browsers, is to set a fixed size for the image wrapping div, the image height, and use the
  CSS Background Size property, which allows you various ways to fill
  the element
- You can also set the css height property to a fixed amount, i.e.,

  ```
   <div class="img-wrap"><img src="..."/></div>

   div.img-wrap {
       overflow:hidden;
       height:100px;
    }
    div.img-wrap img {
       width:auto;
       height: 100px;
    }
  ```
- If you really want to do it programmatically, you can use
  a JQuery plugin like Image Resize

Answer (score 1):

You can set width and height of any image via CSS. If you set only width or only height, it will scale the other dimension to keep the width/height ratio.

In css, you can do something like this:

```
#slider img {
    width: 600px;
}
```